# Ability to Merge Voice Menu options with Recording Audio with VoiceXML and Plum Voice

Tags: voicexml, plumvoice

I am trying to achieve the same issue mentioned [VoiceXML Record whole call, including menu options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393631/voicexml-record-whole-call-including-menu-options.In) a nutshell, have VoiceXML Record whole call while also including menu options. I need to do this is PlumVoice and as per the suggestions need to look for a vendor extension if available.

I tried to look for the vendor extensions but didn't find it. I am fairly new to VoiceXML.Is anyone familiar if this is possible with PlumVoice(version 3.2.8)?

Basically merging these two blocks of code: where the user can say a menu option using voice mode but also recording the whole audio as a wav file.

Voice Menu Selection

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version="2.0">
<form id="mainmenu">
  <field name="menuchoice">
    <grammar type="application/x-jsgf" mode="voice">
      one|two|three
    </grammar>
      <prompt>
        For sales, say 1.
        For tech support, say 2.
        For company directory, say 3.
      </prompt>
      <filled>
        <if cond="menuchoice=='one'">
          Welcome to sales.
        <elseif cond="menuchoice=='two'"/>
          Welcome to tech support.
        <elseif cond="menuchoice=='three'"/>
          Welcome to the company directory.
        </if>
      </filled>
  </field>
</form>
</vxml>
```

Recording audio input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version="2.0">
  <form>
    <record name="myrecording" type="audio/x-wav" beep="true">
      <prompt>
        Please record a message after the beep.
      </prompt>
​
      <filled>
        You just recorded the following message:
        <value expr="myrecording"/>
        <submit next="submitrecording.php" namelist="myrecording"
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
      </filled>
    </record>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

Is this possible with a PlumVoice(version 3.2.8) vendor extension?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard VoiceXML feature (out of the VoiceXML standard).

Only some VoiceXML interpreters like Voximal can do that by adding extra properties (property record utterance for example).